Flutter Sync with SQFLite and CouchDB
Future<void> startReplication(Database database) async {
  final replicator = await Replicator.create(ReplicatorConfiguration(
    database: database,
    target: UrlEndpoint(Uri.parse('ws://localhost:5984/chatapp')),
    continuous: true,
    authenticator: BasicAuthenticator(username: 'admin', password: 'admin'),
    replicatorType: ReplicatorType.pushAndPull,
    headers: {'CustomHeader': 'SomeHeaderValue'},
  ));
  await replicator.start();
}

database is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Add a CollectionConfiguration for the default collection instead.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
